# python gethostbyaddr unknown host mac

Tags: python, macos, gethostbyaddr

I'm trying to use the socket function gethostbyaddr in python.
It's working perfectly on Linux but not on OSX

It's working on distant address like 8.8.8.8

```
>>> socket.gethostbyaddr('8.8.8.8')
('google-public-dns-a.google.com', ['8.8.8.8.in-addr.arpa'], ['8.8.8.8'])
```

It's also working on lookback 127.0.0.1 :

```
>>> socket.gethostbyaddr('127.0.0.1')
('localhost', ['1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa'], ['127.0.0.1'])
```

But it isn't on a local address 10.102.188.21 :

```
>>> socket.gethostbyaddr('10.102.188.21')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
socket.herror: [Errno 1] Unknown host
```

On a Linux :

```
>>> print(socket.gethostbyaddr('10.102.188.21'))
('Pierre.local', [], ['10.102.188.21'])
```

Query with dig :

```
dig -x 10.102.188.21

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> -x 10.102.188.21
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 21064
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;21.188.102.10.in-addr.arpa.    IN  PTR
```

It isn't a proper PTR entry but it should be gotten by the gethostbyaddr()

Comment: It's not clear from your question whether you would expect that last example to work.  Is there an DNS name associated with 10.102.188.21?  Are other tools (e.g., `host` or `nslookup`) able to reverse the address correctly?

Comment: when I query the ip with dig -x I got a reverse dns name associated with the IP (I updated the question)

Comment: Your dig output means the reverse lookup failed. There is no answer section, only the question section which shows what was queried. There is no DNS entry for that host.

Comment: Yes I agree,  but why on a Linux system I get a hostname correctly (I update the question)

Comment: Are both systems using the same nameserver?

Comment: Yes they are using the same nameserver. On linux I get the hostname of the machine, it's not register in the DNS, but on OSX I don't. I will test it on local switch just to be sure.

Comment: Probably on linux the hostname is resolved using mdns (chech your /etc/nsswitch.conf) and on osx it isn't...

Comment: Yes it's seem so.
Test on a local switch : 
Computers on Linux can get the hostname of all the computers on the network but on OSX I get an unknown host error.

Answer (score 0):

On linux in the /etc/nsswitch.conf there is a mdns option that resolve the hostname.
That's why Linux can resolve the hostname on local network

OS X is supposed to resolve it with mDNS also, as it's part of [zeroconf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking)

Thanks mata for the help and larsks for zeroconf

Comment: OS X absolutely supports multicast DNS (this is a core part of "Zeroconf", the system by which your Mac can automatically discover other devices on the local network).  I suspect something else is going on.

Comment: Yes indeed OS X support it. thanks for the information.